# Proof of these two lemma in analytical number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

in publication On Gaps Between Primitive Roots in
the Hamming Metric by Dietmann, Sharplinski & Elsholtz,
there are 2 lemmas:

[image]

H is a binary entropy function.

[image]

Unfortunately these lemmas are not proved in that publication. They are proved in publications from bibliography, but they are both paid (one is a book over 50 $).
I need proofs of these lemmas.

Do You know a place where these lemmas are proved for free?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried searching on libgen or scihub for the papers/books?

Comment: I made proof of 1st one:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    {k\choose l} = {k-1\choose l-1} + {k-1\choose l} = 2^{(k-1)\cdot H(\frac{l-1}{k})+o(k-1)} + 2^{(k-1)\cdot H(\frac{l}{k})+o(k-1)} = \\ 2^{(k-1)\cdot H(\frac{l}{k})+o(k)} + 2^{(k-1)\cdot H(\frac{l}{k})+o(k)} = 
    2 \cdot 2^{(k-1)\cdot H(\frac{l}{k})+o(k)} = 2^{k\cdot H(\frac{l}{k})+o(k)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Is it correct?